# Java array changing content

Tags: java, arrays, refactoring

At the moment I use a snippet like this:

```
private void updateWidth() {
    rowWidth=new int[]{
            font.getWidth(MainClass.getMain().lang().getString("start"), 120)+20,
            font.getWidth(MainClass.getMain().lang().getString("name")+": "+name+"I", 120)+20,
            font.getWidth(MainClass.getMain().lang().getString("currentHigh"), 120)+20,
            font.getWidth(MainClass.getMain().lang().getString("back"), 120)+20
    };

}
```

But in personal I really don't like row nr 2. Where I always if I update the values, create a new object. 
Is this really okay or am I missing some obvious solution?

Comment: If `rowWidth` is always of length `4`, you could simply override the entries: `rowWidth[0] = ...; rowWith[1] = ...; rowWith[2] = ...; rowWith[3] = ...;`

Answer (score 0):

Creating a temporary object that represents the key is fine, assuming that the same key cannot be constructed statically (e.g. because `name` comes from configuration info of some sort).

You can reduce the declaration a little by creating a utility method to encapsulate some of this logic:

```
private static int getWidth(String key) {
    return font.getWidth(MainClass.getMain().lang().getString(key), 120)+20;
}
```

Now your array can be initialized as follows:

```
rowWidth=new int[]{
    getWidth("start")
,   getWidth("name" + ": " + name + "I")
,   getWidth("currentHigh")
,   getWidth("back")
};
```

Answer (score 0):

your code has a lot of duplicated code that violates [DRP Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), which can be refactored in java-8 as:

```
int[] rowWidth = Stream.of("start","name" + ": " + name + "I","currentHigh","back")
                       .mapToInt(key - > font.getWidth(MainClass.getMain().lang()
                                                      .getString(key) ,120) + 20)
                       .toArray();
```